# When all options are selected, the Group Name is displayed as a selected pill. I'm using React-Select

Tags: reactjs, select, react-select

See this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YiOJ.png) I want "Group A" is show when all the sub-option is selected.

I try to add custome isOptionSelected funtion logic, Change value array structure but then onChange is not working properly. Is there any way to achieve this?